# Validar y activar botón si un formulario es válido - Angular

Tags: angular

Tengo un formulario que cuando es `válido` queda con esta clase `ng-dirty ng-touched ng-valid` y cuando es `inválido` tiene esta clase `ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid`, el motivo de esto es que deseo habilitar el botón de envío cuando el formulario sea válido.

Me gustaría validar el formulario ya que son muchos campos y hacer un if(todos los campos y condición) para activar el botón, sería muy extenso la validación.

Mi formulario:

```
<form #formAdd validate>
 <button class="card card-small btn btn-primary bg-primary" *ngIf="formAdd.hasError" (click)="addUser(userAdd)">
     <span class="p-2">Registrar</span>
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Angular estás utilizando y cómo defines `formAdd` en el componente?

Comment: En mi componente esta como:  formAdd!: formGroup y mi version de angular es > 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el caso de estar utilizando `ReactiveForms` con un objeto `FormGroup`, puedes realizar *property binding* sobre la propiedad `disabled` del botón:

```
<button class="..." [disabled]="formAdd.invalid">
  ...
</button>
```